# How to find a prime no without using my function chk prime as i wish to optimize my algo

Tags: c

```
long long int chkPrime(long long int z)
{   
    int i;

       if(z==1)
          return 0;

      if(z==2)
           return 1;

       for(i=2;i<=z/2;i++)
             if(!(z%i))
                     return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add a question to this post.

Comment: Yeah, you'd better change the return type to `int` or even `unsigned char` as it only returns very small numbers. If you want to pass _very_ big numbers to your function, you can use `unsigned long long` instead of `long long int` if it's supported by your compiler. Functions are quite OK, there's no need to get rid of them, I think.

Comment: You can halve the execution time by weeding out even values of `z` first, then testing with only odd values of `i`. You can futher reduce the execution time by iterating only up to the square root of `z`.

Comment: You should look into the [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a certain number is definitely prime, the fastest (i.e. polynomial runtime) deterministic algorithm is the [AKS-test(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) afaik.

If you want to create primes for a certain range, you should look at [sieving(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Prime_sieves), or, as I would recommend download them as list from the internet (e.g. [here](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt) for the first 10000).

The wikipedia article on sieving mentions two good probabilistic primality test, so I will not mention any more. The test does however only say whether a number is a prime with a large probability (so called probable primes).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above, here is a more efficient function, although OP wanted to know how to *"without using my function"*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int chkPrime(long long int z)
{   
    long long int i, rootz;
    if (z <= 1)
        return 0;
    if (z == 2)
        return 1;
    if (z % 2 == 0)
        return 0;
    rootz = (long long int)sqrt((double)z);
    for (i=3; i<=rootz; i+=2)
        if (z % i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        if (chkPrime(i)) printf("%5lld ", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you do not have to go up to sqrt() I think log2() is enough

Comment: @GRC if you want to find a factor of 121 you have to iterate ***up to 11***, its square root, since 121 has no other factors.

Comment: you can check if sqrt() is whole number before you  enter the function

Comment: @GRC I am already in the function. The square root will be a whole number after it is cast to `long long int` type. If it wasn't, it will be rounded down. If it's rounded up, that can't possibly be a factor that was not already checked: that's the point of iterating up to the sqrt. There might be an error with very large numbers, since `double` does not hold as much significance as `long long int`. In that case  a dedicated square root function for `long long int` is not difficult, but if you want to post a better answer, do so.

Comment: ok here is what I mean:   check if sqrt((double)z); is a fraction if it is than continue into the function, if it is not then it is not prime, like 121 you mentioned above. I am not saying it is bed code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73819/discussion-between-grc-and-weather-vane).

Comment: @GRC sorry, I take your last point: if the square root is a whole number then `z` is a perfect square, no need to iterate.

Comment: I apologize, I mean into for loop not function in my second comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
1. Determine the prime numbers upto sqrt(MaxN) using seive at the beginning of your program.(you need to calculate this only once)
2. Then each time you call chkPrime do this :
   -- determine sqrt(z)
   -- check if the number can be divided with the primes upto sqrt(z)
   -- if can not be divided then z is a prime number otherwise it is not.
```

or, if you don't want to generate prime numbers at the beginning then do the following:

```
   1. determine sqrt(z)
   2. check if the number can be divided with 2
   3. if yes then it's not a prime otherwise goto 4
   4. check if the number can be divided with odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(z)
   5. if yes then it's not a prime otherwise it is a prime number
```

Comment: Your first option isn't feasible, considering the type is `long long int` that would be a massive array.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right (y)
I assumed the input is not that big :( whatever, there is always option 2 :)