# How can I reduce the runtime?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes, number-theory

Here is a link to the problem I'm trying to solve: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1086

Here is my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, m, p;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &m);

        p = find_prime(m);
        printf("%d\n", p);
    }

    return 0;
}

int find_prime(int a)
{
    int i, p = 1, t, prime[15000], j;
    prime[0] = 2;

    for(i = 0; i < a; )
    {
        if(p == 2)
        {
            p++;
        }else
        {
            p = p + 1;
        }
        t = 0;
        for(j = 0; prime[j] <= sqrt(p); j++)
        {
            if(p%prime[j] == 0 && p != 2)
            {
                t = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(t != 1)
        {
            i++;
            prime[i] = p;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

I know the algorithm is fine and it produces the correct answer. But I always get "Time Limit Exceeded". I can't get the runtime download to 2 seconds. It's always equal to 2.031 seconds. I have tried few other approaches, for example, I iterated through all the numbers until I found the mth prime number, I tried skipping the even integers greater than 2 but I still get 2.031 seconds.

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a prime no without using my function chk prime as i wish to optimize my algo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260160/how-to-find-a-prime-no-without-using-my-function-chk-prime-as-i-wish-to-optimize)

Comment: You might use a [sieve of Erastosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: What do you consider to be the difference in behaviour between the two branches of `if(p == 2)
        {
            p++;
        }else
        {
            p = p + 1;
        }`?  To me, it looks as though `p` is incremented by one regardless of its initial value.   —— And I see that [Ed Heal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) pointed this out in his [not really an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29321669/15168).

Comment: since waiting for a user to input some sequence of number is massive, timewise, compared to the actual execution is seems unrealistic to focus your attention of the execution time of the find_prime() function

Comment: when calling scanf() (or any of that family of functions) the code should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure that the operation was successful

Answer (score 3):

Your buffer for prime numbers doesn't need to be a local variable that's recalculated every time.

You can try to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) by storing the buffer in the global scope and using a global counter to keep track of how many primes you have already calculated until now and which number was the maximum number requested.

If the next number that's requested from you is smaller than the previous maximum, you should fall back to the corresponding pre-calculated number. If the next number is larger than the previous maximum, make it the new maximum - and also try to start calculating from where you last left off.

Comment: Why not pre-compute all primes less than 15000? He's got 64 MB of memory to work with. That should be plenty.

Comment: @Seamus I intentionally described a general solution. Of course, for the sizes we're talking about, your suggestion about pre-computing is perfectly valid (and will most likely be more performant). And in a real-world scenario, probably a combination of both techniques would be viable.

Comment: @seamus, wouldn't that take a lot of time? and the numbers i input can't be greater than 15000, not the prime numbers.

Comment: @lucid.dreamer You're computing all these numbers during runtime anyway. It won't take longer than that to precompute them just once and hardcode them in your file.

Comment: @lucid.dreamer for general reference, it took me 60 ms to compute a sieve of erthostene until 163,841 (#15,000 prime) with a naive implementation of algorithm in python. So, no it would not take so much time.

Comment: Exactly. Even if you needed the first 15000 primes, you could compute then in advance. Then your function would take input n, and simply look up the nth number in your hardcoded array of primes. Super fast.

Comment: This is my new approach: I determined the largest input(suppose n) and then computed all the prime numbers till the nth prime and then simply looked up the prime numbers I needed. Still takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
  if(p == 2)
    {
        p++;
    }else
    {
        p = p + 1;
    }
```

and replace it with

```
p++
```

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't do me any good. So I thought if I could skip the integers that are obviously non-prime, it might take less time.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it,

the problem is to find the next prime greater that the sum of all the prior input numbers.

That means there are certain expectations.

```
1) the sum of the prior input numbers is available in find_prime(). 
2) for simplification, the last found prime number is available in find_prime().
```

Neither of these expectations are implemented.

Then there is that 60 thousand byte array on the stack in find_prime().

Suggest moving that to a file global position and including a 'static' modifier.

move the prior sum of inputs to a file global location, so it is always available.

for overall speed,

calculate all the primes in the array as a first thing, thereby filling the array with prime values.  then

```
1) add new input to sum, 
2) index into array using sum. 
3) return value found in array.
```